# Should I need to install jdk separately for Android studio in 2018?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Some people say you should install the latest version of JDK separately to develop Android applications in Android Studio. 
Some say you don't need to because Android Studio already has an embedded JDK.

What's the matter? What should I do?

Comment: nothing but your choice. you should google it before question about it.

Comment: You should, since you're developing Android App. No problem at all. Actually there's a lot of tutorial mentioning about the need of Java JDK as later we'll using Java API that's included in Java JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's no need for external JDK to develop android apps. The embedded OpenJDK will do a great job.